# ANDROID: Saving PreviewCallback image as a .jpg from a byte array results in a corrupt file

Tags: java, android, save, photo, zxing

I have been augmenting the QR scanning library Zxing to save a photo instantly upon scan. I was advised to do so within the onPreviewFrame method within PreviewCallback.java as thus:

```
 public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
Point cameraResolution = configManager.getCameraResolution();
Handler thePreviewHandler = previewHandler;

YuvImage im = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, 1200,
        800, null);
        Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, 1200, 800);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        im.compressToJpeg(r, 50, baos);

        try {
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/test_jpg.jpg");
            output.write(baos.toByteArray());
            output.flush();
            output.close();

            System.out.println("Attempting to save file");
            System.out.println(data);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Saving to file failed");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Saving to file failed");
        }

if (cameraResolution != null && thePreviewHandler != null) {
  Message message = thePreviewHandler.obtainMessage(previewMessage, cameraResolution.x,
      cameraResolution.y, data);
  message.sendToTarget();
  previewHandler = null;

} else {
  Log.d(TAG, "Got preview callback, but no handler or resolution available");
}}
```

The result of running this code is a corrupt image at the set file directory. I believe this is due to the code being run every frame. Is there a way to limit this to every second or so if that will allow the full image to save, or is there a method I can use to cause the image to only save upon completed scan.

I have a less favourable working alternative, in that I can successfully save the black and white image that is shown upon scan; colour is the preferable option of course.

---

Update: Code changed to (in theory) accommodate camera resolution on any device. Image is still corrupt.

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
Point cameraResolution = configManager.getCameraResolution();
Handler thePreviewHandler = previewHandler;

android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
android.hardware.Camera.Size size = parameters.getPictureSize();

int height = size.height;
int width = size.width;

YuvImage im = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, width,
        height, null);
        Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        im.compressToJpeg(r, 50, baos);

        try {
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/test_jpg.jpg");
            output.write(baos.toByteArray());
            output.flush();
            output.close();

            System.out.println("Attempting to save file");
            System.out.println(data);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {             
            System.out.println("Saving to file failed");                
        } catch (IOException e) {               
            System.out.println("Saving to file failed");                
        }    
if (cameraResolution != null && thePreviewHandler != null) {
  Message message = thePreviewHandler.obtainMessage(previewMessage, cameraResolution.x,
      cameraResolution.y, data);
  message.sendToTarget();
  previewHandler = null;

} else {
  Log.d(TAG, "Got preview callback, but no handler or resolution available");
}}
```

Having checked the width and height variable are correctly set to the Nexus 7's camera width and height of 1280x960. I am confident the issue comes from attempting to save the image every frame, as "Attempting to save to file" appears somewhat rapidly within the logcat; several times a second. It may also be worth noting that the corrupt image saved is square(ish).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note you are using `getPictureSize()` to get the Size object. The size of the preview is given by  `getPreviewSize`. In many cases the two are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1200 x 800? are you sure this is your preview size? check your parameters. Probably it's 1280 x 720

Comment: yeah it's camera, check your camera preview size

Comment: How do I find the camera height on width for any device? I've seen it done through Camera.getParamters but I'm having trouble finding proper sample code.

Comment: OP updated with what should accommodate any camera size, image still corrupts.

Comment: You should use getPreviewSize () not getPictureSize(), I think they are different. Have a try

Comment: Thank you, this now works successfully, however the I do not have a way of making only a single photo be saved upon scan. I shall ask a new question for help with this issue.

Thanks again.

Comment: New question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232992/android-zxing-saving-a-photo-in-onpreviewframe-saves-a-photo-every-frame-how-t

Any help would be greatly appreciated.